# Passing PHP Values to Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to pass PHP values from the DB to a bootstrap modal which is a form that posts to some other page, I think I am close but i can't figure out why the bootstrap modal -text box won't the values from PHP, I followed Ashish's article and got very close, but just not able to get the values to the bootstrap modal.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the HTML and the PHP part of the code.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered datatables" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Cell</th>                                    
            <th>Appointment On</th>
            <th>Modify Status</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                              <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getenqs)) 
                              {
                               echo '<tr>';
                               echo '<td>'.$cnt.'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custname'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custemail'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custcell'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.datemaker($row['enq_date']).'</td>';
                               echo '<td align="center"><a data-toggle="modal" data-enid'.$cnt.'="'.$row['id'].'"  href="#addappModal'.$cnt.'" class="caddappModal'.$cnt.'"><i class="fa fa-calendar showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo '<td align="center"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#modstatModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add as a Member" href="ajax/add-as-member?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-share showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hide this enquiry" href="ajax/hide-enquiry?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo '</tr>';
                               ?>
                        <!-- Modal to Add Appointments-->
                        <form action="addapp" class="form-horizontal row-border"  data-validate="parsley" id="validate-form">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="addappModal<?php echo $cnt;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header panel-green">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add an Appointment for <?php echo $row['custname']; ?></h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body" id="addapp" >

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Required Field</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <input type="text" required="required"  class="form-control" id="datepicker">
                                                    <input type="text" name="enid" id="fenid<?php echo $cnt;?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                                    <button class="btn-green btn" id="demoskylo" onclick="javascript:$('#validate-form').parsley( 'validate' );">&nbsp;Add Appointment</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>
                        </form><!-- /.modal to add appointments ends-->                                
                              <?php 
                             $cnt++;  } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i=1; i<=<?php echo $cnt;?>; i++) { 
            $('a.caddappModal'+i).click(function(){
                var enid = $(this).data('enid'+i);
                $('#fenid'+i).val(enid);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: Hi, The data from the DB is shown in a data table, i have an icon clicking on which a bootstrap modal shows up which is form, clicking on this form the values are passed to the other page which processes the data from the form. The problem is that I need the bootstrap to get the ID of the data (from the row) which was clicked, thats not happening. That is, the                                                     <input type="text" name="enid" id="fenid<?php echo $cnt;?>">
 section on the modal should contain the $row['id'], this is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

try the below code, I did not test it but might give you idea.

```
                        <!-- Modal to Add Appointments-->
                        <form action="addapp" class="form-horizontal row-border"  data-validate="parsley" id="validate-form">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="addappModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header panel-green">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add an Appointment for <?php echo $row['custname']; ?></h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body" id="addapp" >

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Required Field</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <input type="text" required="required"  class="form-control" id="datepicker">
                                                    <input type="text" name="enid" id="id" value="">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                                    <button class="btn-green btn" id="demoskylo" onclick="javascript:$('#validate-form').parsley( 'validate' );">&nbsp;Add Appointment</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

                        </div>
                        </form><!-- /.modal to add appointments ends-->  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".caddappModal", function () {
     var pId = $(this).data('enid');
       $(".modal-body #id").val( pId );
});</script>  

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered datatables" id="example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sr.No</th>
                                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Cell</th>                                    
                                    <th>Appointment On</th>
                                    <th>Modify Status</th>
                                    <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getenqs)) 
                              {
                               echo '<tr>';
                               echo '<td>'.$cnt.'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custname'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custemail'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.$row['custcell'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>'.datemaker($row['enq_date']).'</td>';
                               echo '<td align="center"><a data-toggle="modal" data-enid="'.$row['id'].'"  href="#addappModal" class="caddappModal"><i class="fa fa-calendar showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo '<td align="center"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#modstatModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add as a Member" href="ajax/add-as-member?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-share showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hide this enquiry" href="ajax/hide-enquiry?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo '</tr>';
                             $cnt++;  } ?>
                            </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Php code to this

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered datatables" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sr.No</th>
                                <th>Customer Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Cell</th>                                    
                                <th>Appointment On</th>
                                <th>Modify Status</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getenqs)) 
                          {
                           echo '<tr>';
                           echo '<td>'.$cnt.'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$row['custname'].'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$row['custemail'].'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.$row['custcell'].'</td>';
                           echo '<td>'.datemaker($row['enq_date']).'</td>';
                           echo '<td align="center">
<a class="launchModal" data-enid="'.$row['id'].'" data-cn="'.$row['custname'].'" href="#addappModal" class="caddappModal"><i class="fa fa-calendar showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo '<td align="center"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#modstatModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil showgreen"></i></a></td>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add as a Member" href="ajax/add-as-member?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-share showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo'<td align="center"><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hide this enquiry" href="ajax/hide-enquiry?enqid='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle showgreen"></i></a>';
                               echo '</tr>';

                          <?php 
                           } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<form action="addapp" class="form-horizontal row-border"  data-validate="parsley" id="validate-form">
                        <div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header panel-green">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add an Appointment for <span id="cn"></span></h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body" id="addapp" >

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Required Field</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6" >
                                                    <input type="text" required="required"  class="form-control" id="datepicker">
                                                    <div id="FormCon"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                                    <button class="btn-green btn" id="demoskylo" onclick="javascript:$('#validate-form').parsley( 'validate' );">&nbsp;Add Appointment</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Java script to

```
$(function(){
$('.launchModal').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var enid = $(this).data('enid');
$('#FormCon').html('<input type="text" name="enid" value="'+enid+'" />');
$('#cn').html($(this).data('cn'));
$('.modal').modal();
};

})
```

Comment: Is the modal launching?

Comment: Yes the modal is launching, but the text box inside is not receiving the value..I can not figure out why though.